Создание псевдонима на несуществующий метод
class Delegate {
private:
    struct X {
    };
    typedef void (X::*Func)();
    Func _func;
};

Структура X не имеет метода Func, но почему-то есть возможность создать псевдоним.

Это не псевдоним метода, а псевдоним типа.

В С++ вообще нет псевдонимов для методов.

Func - это имя псевдонима (для типа), а не имя метода.
Будет нагляднее если переписать через using: typedef void (X::*Func)(); - то же самое, что using Func = void (X::*)();.

Точнее, псевдоним для типа метода структуры X. Структура X не имеет метода Func. Псевдоним просто для типа функции выглядел бы так: typedef void (*Func)(); или using Func = void (*)();

@Евгений "Структура X не имеет метода Func" Неважно, это же не имя метода. Вот если бы вы попробовали написать Func _func = &X::blah; - тогда была бы ошибка, потому что нет метода blah.
